# Substract Days to a Date in HIVE APACHE

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql

How I can substract a number of days of a date, having as a result another date, for example: 01/12/2016 - 10 = 21/11/2016

Comment: Where? Like in a HiveQL query?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Folks here are excited  and eager to help you with your question but it's important to help them help you. Consider building a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's important because it shows what you've already tried, your thought process, and what you're hoping to achieve. Also consider using [backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for code sections, it increases readability. For example `41 + 1 = 42` is easier to read than 41 + 1 = 42. Again welcome and good skills moving forward :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(date argument)

```
hive> select date_sub(date '2016-12-01',10);
OK
2016-11-21
```

or

(string argument)

```
hive> select date_sub('2016-12-01',10);
OK
2016-11-21
```

> **date_sub(date/timestamp/string startdate, tinyint/smallint/int days)**
>
> Subtracts a number of days to startdate: date_sub('2008-12-31', 1) =
>   '2008-12-30'. Prior to Hive 2.1.0 (HIVE-13248) the return type was a
>   String because no Date type existed when the method was created.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Answer (score 1):

there exist a hive udf to substract days to the hive datehttps://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions, you have two options, transform your date to the following format to use the udf directly

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

or you can transform your current date to timestamp and apply the udf, for example

```
date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('12/03/2010' , 'dd/MM/yyyy')), 10) -- subs 10 days
```

I hope it helps,
regards!